# Problems with SCSS and / or js frome CodePen

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass, codepen

I'm trying to use a [template from CodePen](https://codepen.io/teeganlincoln/pen/MaNxBv), yet however I try, I can't get it to work. It's surely some sort of basic mistake I'm making. If any of you could tell me what it is, taht'd be splendid. I used an Atom plugin + Ruby to compile the .scss code.

I started with HTML Biolerplate, but the figured it might be causing some problems due to conflicts from unnecessary bits and pieces, so I started a barebone file, but am getting the same result.

Both jquery.min.js and gallery.css are placed in correct folders, BTW.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

   var $sm = 480;
   var $md = 768;

   function resizeThis() {
      $imgH = $('.middle img').width();
      if ($(window).width() >= $sm) {
         $('.left,.right,.section').css('height', $imgH);
      } else {
         $('.left,.right,.section').css('height', 'auto');
      }
   }

   resizeThis();

   $(window).resize(function(){
      resizeThis();
   });

   $(window).scroll(function() {
      $('.section').each(function(){
         var $elementPos = $(this).offset().top;
         var $scrollPos = $(window).scrollTop();

         var $sectionH = $(this).height();
         var $h = $(window).height();
         var $sectionVert = (($h/2)-($sectionH/4));


         if (($elementPos - $sectionVert) <= $scrollPos && ($elementPos - $sectionVert) + $sectionH > $scrollPos) {
            $(this).addClass('animate');
         } else {
            $(this).removeClass('animate');
         }
      });
   });

   $('.btn-primary').click(function(){
      alert('I lied');
   });
});

$(function() {
  $('a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,900);
body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif; }

.header, .footer {
  background: #2e2e2e;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 30px;
  text-align: center; }
  .header a, .footer a {
    color: #fff; }
  @media (min-width: 768px) {
    .header, .footer {
      padding: 100px 30px; } }
  .header h1, .footer h1 {
    font-size: 4em;
    font-weight: 300; }
  .header i.fa, .footer i.fa {
    font-size: 4em; }
  .header .bounce, .footer .bounce {
    -webkit-animation-name: bounce;
    animation-name: bounce;
    -webkit-transform-origin: center bottom;
    transform-origin: center bottom;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite; }
  .header .animated, .footer .animated {
    -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
    animation-duration: 2s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
    animation-fill-mode: both; }

.section {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative; }
  .section .left, .section .middle, .section .right {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    color: #fff;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    left: 0;
    padding: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    -moz-transition: 0.3s ease-in-out all;
    -o-transition: 0.3s ease-in-out all;
    -webkit-transition: 0.3s ease-in-out all;
    transition: 0.3s ease-in-out all; }
    @media (min-width: 480px) {
      .section .left .content, .section .middle .content, .section .right .content {
        position: relative;
        top: 50%;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
        -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
        transform: translateY(-50%); } }
    @media (min-width: 480px) {
      .section .left, .section .middle, .section .right {
        width: 50%;
        font-size: 0.9em;
        padding: 10px;
        left: 0;
        float: left;
        position: absolute; } }
    @media (min-width: 768px) {
      .section .left, .section .middle, .section .right {
        width: 33.33333%;
        left: 33.33%;
        padding: 10px; } }
    @media (min-width: 992px) {
      .section .left, .section .middle, .section .right {
        padding: 30px;
        font-size: 1em; } }
  .section.animate .left {
    left: 0; }
    @media (min-width: 480px) {
      .section.animate .left {
        left: 50%; } }
    @media (min-width: 768px) {
      .section.animate .left {
        left: 0; } }
  .section.animate .right {
    left: 0; }
    @media (min-width: 480px) {
      .section.animate .right {
        left: 50%; } }
    @media (min-width: 768px) {
      .section.animate .right {
        left: 66.66%; } }
  .section .title {
    background: tomato; }
    .section .title h2 {
      margin-top: 0; }
    .section .title p {
      line-height: 1.55em;
      margin-bottom: 0.75em; }
    .section .title .btn-primary {
      color: #fff;
      background: #ff3814;
      padding: 10px;
      text-decoration: none;
      border-radius: 3px;
      display: inline-block;
      -moz-transition: 0.3s ease-in-out all;
      -o-transition: 0.3s ease-in-out all;
      -webkit-transition: 0.3s ease-in-out all;
      transition: 0.3s ease-in-out all; }
      .section .title .btn-primary:hover {
        background: #fa2600; }
  .section .tiles {
    padding: 0;
    background: #fff;
    clear: both;
    display: none;
    float: none; }
    .section .tiles img {
      width: 50%;
      float: left;
      height: auto;
      opacity: 0.7;
      -moz-transition: 0.3s ease-in-out all;
      -o-transition: 0.3s ease-in-out all;
      -webkit-transition: 0.3s ease-in-out all;
      transition: 0.3s ease-in-out all;
      -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
      -moz-filter: grayscale(100%);
      -o-filter: grayscale(100%); }
      .section .tiles img:hover {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
        -moz-filter: grayscale(0%);
        -o-filter: grayscale(0%); }
    @media (min-width: 768px) {
      .section .tiles {
        display: block; } }
  .section .middle {
    background: slategray;
    z-index: 2;
    padding: 0; }
    .section .middle img {
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
      display: block; }

@-webkit-keyframes bounce {
  0%, 20%, 50%, 80%, 100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0); }
  40% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-20px); }
  60% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-10px); } }
@keyframes bounce {
  0%, 20%, 50%, 80%, 100% {
    transform: translateY(0); }
  40% {
    transform: translateY(-20px); }
  60% {
    transform: translateY(-10px); } }

/*# sourceMappingURL=gallery.css.map */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/gallery.css">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="header" id="top">
     <h1>Scroll Down</h1>
     <i class="fa fa-angle-down animated bounce"></i>
  </div>

  <div class="section animate">
     <div class="middle">
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1460400408855-36abd76648b9?dpr=2&auto=format&crop=entropy&fit=crop&w=250&h=250&q=80" />
     </div>
     <div class="left title">
        <div class="content">
           <h2>A glorious nature shot.</h2>
           <p>Wow. What a wonderful image. And look! there are even more images on the right side. Amazing. If you click below, I bet you'll get teleported to a magical land.</p>
           <a href="#" class="btn-primary">Learn more</a>
        </div>
     </div>
     <div class="right tiles">
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1460400408855-36abd76648b9?dpr=2&auto=format&crop=entropy&fit=crop&w=250&h=250&q=80" />
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1460400408855-36abd76648b9?dpr=2&auto=format&crop=entropy&fit=crop&w=250&h=250&q=80" />
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1460400408855-36abd76648b9?dpr=2&auto=format&crop=entropy&fit=crop&w=250&h=250&q=80" />
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1460400408855-36abd76648b9?dpr=2&auto=format&crop=entropy&fit=crop&w=250&h=250&q=80" />
     </div>
  </div>

  <div class="section">
     <div class="middle">
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1464655646192-3cb2ace7a67e?dpr=2&auto=format&crop=entropy&fit=crop&w=250&h=250&q=80" />
     </div>
     <div class="right title">
        <div class="content">
           <h2>Check out this guy.</h2>
           <p>What an interesting looking person! I wonder if they've ever climbed Mount Everest, or seen the Egyptian Pyramids. If not, I hope that one day they get to. You go random stock image person! Follow your dreams!</p>
        </div>
     </div>

     <div class="left tiles">
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1464655646192-3cb2ace7a67e?dpr=2&auto=format&crop=entropy&fit=crop&w=250&h=250&q=80" />
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1464655646192-3cb2ace7a67e?dpr=2&auto=format&crop=entropy&fit=crop&w=250&h=250&q=80" />
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1464655646192-3cb2ace7a67e?dpr=2&auto=format&crop=entropy&fit=crop&w=250&h=250&q=80" />
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1464655646192-3cb2ace7a67e?dpr=2&auto=format&crop=entropy&fit=crop&w=250&h=250&q=80" />
     </div>

  </div>

  <div class="section">
     <div class="middle">
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1465326117523-6450112b60b2?dpr=2&auto=format&crop=entropy&fit=crop&w=250&h=250&q=80" />
     </div>
     <div class="left title">
        <div class="content">
           <h2>That is one pretty building.</h2>
           <p>I once thought about becoming an architect. I wanted to create a house fit for a king. But then I failed maths. So I became a frontend developer instead.</p>
        </div>
     </div>

     <div class="right tiles">
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1465326117523-6450112b60b2?dpr=2&auto=format&crop=entropy&fit=crop&w=250&h=250&q=80" />
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1465326117523-6450112b60b2?dpr=2&auto=format&crop=entropy&fit=crop&w=250&h=250&q=80" />
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1465326117523-6450112b60b2?dpr=2&auto=format&crop=entropy&fit=crop&w=250&h=250&q=80" />
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1465326117523-6450112b60b2?dpr=2&auto=format&crop=entropy&fit=crop&w=250&h=250&q=80" />
     </div>

  </div>

  <div class="section">
     <div class="middle">
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1464822759023-fed622ff2c3b?dpr=2&auto=format&crop=entropy&fit=crop&w=250&h=250&q=80" />
     </div>
     <div class="right title">
        <div class="content">
           <h2>The future is now.</h2>
           <p>Check out that technology! Imagine if we went back in time and put one of those in the hands of a neanderthal. Do you think they'd be impressed, or just try to club us to death?</p>
        </div>
     </div>

     <div class="left tiles">
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1464822759023-fed622ff2c3b?dpr=2&auto=format&crop=entropy&fit=crop&w=250&h=250&q=80" />
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1464822759023-fed622ff2c3b?dpr=2&auto=format&crop=entropy&fit=crop&w=250&h=250&q=80" />
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1464822759023-fed622ff2c3b?dpr=2&auto=format&crop=entropy&fit=crop&w=250&h=250&q=80" />
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1464822759023-fed622ff2c3b?dpr=2&auto=format&crop=entropy&fit=crop&w=250&h=250&q=80" />
     </div>

  </div>

  <div class="footer">
     <a href="#top" class="scrollTo"><i class="fa fa-angle-up animated bounce"></i></a>
     <h1>Scroll Up</h1>
  </div>

  <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit tough to give a solution, not knowing exactly what you're seeing on your end, but there are a few things that stuck out to me.  After I changed these things, everything was peachy on my end.  Please keep in mind, I just copy-pasta'd your three files into 3 local files of my own and ran with Live Server on VSCode.

I added jQuery 2.1.3 from the [jQuery CDN](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js) (the specific version the author of that Pen used) to the `<head>` of the html file.  I also added the [FontAwesome CDN](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css) that the author used for that Pen.  Lastly, it doesn't look like you were referencing your script file from anywhere in your html file.  I added that just before the closing `</body>` tag.

[===clarity edits===]

jQuery is a JavaScript library, which (at least in this case) is used for DOM manipulation (there is a good [explanation of "the DOM"](https://css-tricks.com/dom/) on CSS-Tricks).  jQuery, by itself, doesn't really do anything...it just simplifies how you do things.  The library itself must be added to your html file, so that your code knows what some of those symbols/functions mean (the `$.()` notation, for example).

When the html document loads to the DOM, it loads top down.  Since your .js file is trying to manipulate elements in the DOM, you need for them to exist first.  This is why I suggested putting your .js file just before the closing `</body>` tag.  This part of my original answer was partially incorrect, because your .js file is making use of the `$(document).ready()` jQuery function (which I didn't initially notice).  As long as you are still loading the jQuery library before your .js file, it shouldn't matter where you put it, funcionality-wise.

It is worth noting, however, that linking the .js file in the `<head>` blocks rendering.  While this may not be a problem for the demo you're playing with, or a very small amount of Javascript, it gets less performant as it increases in size.  There's a [decent explanation](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/BlockingJS) over on the Google Developer site, where they also discuss async loading of .js files.

[===end clarity edits===]

All in all, this is what my HTML file looked like.  I changed nothing else in between.

```html
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js">. 
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  [ALL THE HTML HERE]
  [LAST THING IN THE BODY TAG...This would need to be the name of your javascript file]
  <script src="scripts.js"></script>
</body>
```

My best advice when grabbing things off of CodePen is to check the little gear icon next to the HTML / CSS / JS headings and make sure you are importing not just the things that they are, but the specific versions, if you are looking to have the exact same behavior.

Lastly, it's always nice to credit the CodePen author (even if it is just in a comment somewhere).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="header" id="top">
    <h1>Scroll Down</h1>
    <i class="fa fa-angle-down animated bounce"></i>
  </div>

  <div class="section animate">
    <div class="middle">
      <img
        src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1460400408855-36abd76648b9?dpr=2&auto=format&crop=entropy&fit=crop&w=250&h=250&q=80" />
    </div>
    <div class="left title">
      <div class="content">
        <h2>A glorious nature shot.</h2>
        <p>Wow. What a wonderful image. And look! there are even more images on the right side. Amazing. If you click
          below, I bet you'll get teleported to a magical land.</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn-primary">Learn more</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="right tiles">
      <img
        src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1460400408855-36abd76648b9?dpr=2&auto=format&crop=entropy&fit=crop&w=250&h=250&q=80" />
      <img
        src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1460400408855-36abd76648b9?dpr=2&auto=format&crop=entropy&fit=crop&w=250&h=250&q=80" />
      <img
        src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1460400408855-36abd76648b9?dpr=2&auto=format&crop=entropy&fit=crop&w=250&h=250&q=80" />
      <img
        src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1460400408855-36abd76648b9?dpr=2&auto=format&crop=entropy&fit=crop&w=250&h=250&q=80" />
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="section">
    <div class="middle">
      <img
        src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1464655646192-3cb2ace7a67e?dpr=2&auto=format&crop=entropy&fit=crop&w=250&h=250&q=80" />
    </div>
    <div class="right title">
      <div class="content">
        <h2>Check out this guy.</h2>
        <p>What an interesting looking person! I wonder if they've ever climbed Mount Everest, or seen the Egyptian
          Pyramids. If not, I hope that one day they get to. You go random stock image person! Follow your dreams!</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="left tiles">
      <img
        src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1464655646192-3cb2ace7a67e?dpr=2&auto=format&crop=entropy&fit=crop&w=250&h=250&q=80" />
      <img
        src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1464655646192-3cb2ace7a67e?dpr=2&auto=format&crop=entropy&fit=crop&w=250&h=250&q=80" />
      <img
        src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1464655646192-3cb2ace7a67e?dpr=2&auto=format&crop=entropy&fit=crop&w=250&h=250&q=80" />
      <img
        src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1464655646192-3cb2ace7a67e?dpr=2&auto=format&crop=entropy&fit=crop&w=250&h=250&q=80" />
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="section">
    <div class="middle">
      <img
        src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1465326117523-6450112b60b2?dpr=2&auto=format&crop=entropy&fit=crop&w=250&h=250&q=80" />
    </div>
    <div class="left title">
      <div class="content">
        <h2>That is one pretty building.</h2>
        <p>I once thought about becoming an architect. I wanted to create a house fit for a king. But then I failed
          maths. So I became a frontend developer instead.</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="right tiles">
      <img
        src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1465326117523-6450112b60b2?dpr=2&auto=format&crop=entropy&fit=crop&w=250&h=250&q=80" />
      <img
        src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1465326117523-6450112b60b2?dpr=2&auto=format&crop=entropy&fit=crop&w=250&h=250&q=80" />
      <img
        src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1465326117523-6450112b60b2?dpr=2&auto=format&crop=entropy&fit=crop&w=250&h=250&q=80" />
      <img
        src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1465326117523-6450112b60b2?dpr=2&auto=format&crop=entropy&fit=crop&w=250&h=250&q=80" />
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="section">
    <div class="middle">
      <img
        src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1464822759023-fed622ff2c3b?dpr=2&auto=format&crop=entropy&fit=crop&w=250&h=250&q=80" />
    </div>
    <div class="right title">
      <div class="content">
        <h2>The future is now.</h2>
        <p>Check out that technology! Imagine if we went back in time and put one of those in the hands of a
          neanderthal. Do you think they'd be impressed, or just try to club us to death?</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="left tiles">
      <img
        src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1464822759023-fed622ff2c3b?dpr=2&auto=format&crop=entropy&fit=crop&w=250&h=250&q=80" />
      <img
        src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1464822759023-fed622ff2c3b?dpr=2&auto=format&crop=entropy&fit=crop&w=250&h=250&q=80" />
      <img
        src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1464822759023-fed622ff2c3b?dpr=2&auto=format&crop=entropy&fit=crop&w=250&h=250&q=80" />
      <img
        src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1464822759023-fed622ff2c3b?dpr=2&auto=format&crop=entropy&fit=crop&w=250&h=250&q=80" />
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="footer">
    <a href="#top" class="scrollTo"><i class="fa fa-angle-up animated bounce"></i></a>
    <h1>Scroll Up</h1>
  </div>
<script src="scripts.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, Jason.

So a question first: I'm using Atom, but from what I gather, Live Server is just a plugin that updates changes on-the-go as you code, right? So if I save a file and refresh in Firefox for example, that's the same?

Comment: Secondly, I applied the tweaks, yet to no avail. Actually the result was this time a completely blank page.

You say you're not seeing JQuery in my code, but there it is, at the end of the <body>. I even downloaded it and saved locally in js folder. Plus you're putting it in the <head> - I thought these ought to go right before </body>??
And am I supposed to put <script src="scripts.js"></script> in the body, even if there's no other scripts running on that site?

Comment: After just putting a link to online source of JQuery + that font (I did miss that one), I am getting pretty much the same result as before, but now the "scroll down" section font is correct and the arrow down moves.

Here's a static image of my result:
https://ibb.co/CbgBtXq

Comment: OK, so I did exactly what you said, and it does get better: the layout is correct now (a column with four pics), but as I load the site, the sides are expanded and collapse as I scroll down (opposite to expand as you scroll down/up - as on CodePen)

Comment: Yes, saving, then reloading should be doing the same thing as Live-Server, which just handles the reloading for you.  Regarding jQuery, there are two scripts at play: the actual jQuery library (which enables the use of jQuery functions and the $. syntax) and your jQuery code (which manipulates things using the library).  The library needs to be loaded before your script file so that your script knows what the jQuery functions are.  Since jQuery is used (in this case) as a DOM manipulation tool, it needs to run after all of the DOM nodes have shown up.  I'll edit my main post to clarify.